# can't echo wpdb result

Tags: php, count, wordpress

I'm pulling information from the WordPress database. It's definitely pulling all the correct information and if I display the information with `print_r( $res, true )` it shows what i require which is:

[term_id] => 8
[name] => Africa
[slug] => africa
[COUNT(a.id)] => 1

I need to echo the `COUNT(a.id)` but I can't seem to manage this? My full code is here: http://pastie.org/4121409

I have managed to echo all the other information, just not the `COUNT(a.id)`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When selecting, use column aliases, like this: `COUNT(a.id) AS id_count`

Then it will appear as the field name in result set, instead of `COUNT(a.id)` and you will be able to access it by `$rs->id_count`

Also note that in your original code, line 22 will break the code. It should have been `$counter = "COUNT(a.id)";`

Comment: Thank you so so much! I will name my first 3 children Poncha.